# Applying method to objects in a numpy array with vectorize results in empty array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to apply a method to each object in a numpy array. I thought of using numpy.vectorize to speed things up, but I get an empty array instead. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Here's the code:

```
import numpy

class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = None
  def SetX(self, x):
    self.x = x
# Initialize and array of Foo objects
y = numpy.empty( 3, dtype=object )
vFoo = numpy.vectorize(lambda x: Foo() )
yfoo = vFoo(y)
# Apply method SetX to each object
xsetter = numpy.vectorize( lambda foo: foo.SetX(3.45) )
print xsetter(yfoo) #[None None None]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general you don't need to define `set` (or `get`) functions for custom classes: just use `Foo_inst.x=y` to set, where `Foo_inst` is your class object, `x` is the desired attribute and `y` is its desired value. This is true even if the attribute `x` hasn't been explicitly defined before. Similarly, just use `Foo_inst.x` to get its value.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's just that I like to keep a facade of privacy for class attributes :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the lambda function return values is None (the result of `Foo.SetX`), you can do this:

```
def f(foo):
    foo.SetX(3.45)
    return foo
xsetter = numpy.vectorize( f )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `SetX` method does not return a value. One way to fix this would be by rewriting `SetX` as

```
def SetX(self, x):
  self.x = x
  return self
```